# Conjugacy classes of $\mathop{\mathrm{GL}}_{10}(\mathbb{Q})$ with certain minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules, minimal-polynomials

How many conjugacy classes of matrices are there in $\mathop{\mathrm{GL}}_{10}(\mathbb{Q})$ with minimal polynomial $X^7 − 4X^3$?

I initially thought that since $0$ is a root of the minimal polynomial, it is also an eigenvalue. But if a matrix has $0$ as an eigenvalue, it has a nontrivial kernel, and hence is not invertible. In particular, it is not in $\mathop{\mathrm{GL}}_{10}(\mathbb{Q})$, so the answer to the question above is that there are no such conjugacy glasses?

As this was posed as a supposedly hard exam question, I find it hard to believe that the solution should be this simple - where does the argument above fail?

Comment: With the current statement, I'd say you are correct. You might want to check with your teacher if the assignment has been stated as intended.

Comment: The problem is from the 2nd year exams at Cambridge last year. It is problem 11G (on page 5) in this pdf: https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers/files/2019/paperib_4_2019.pdf